# What does it mean when it says 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare the following:

```
if (e.CreatedBy == null)
```

But this is giving me an error saying:

> The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type
>   'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'

Can someone help tell me how I can check if the value of CreatedBy has not been set yet? Note here's the definition of CreatedBy:

```
public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

Comment: You would either need to check `e.CreatedBy == 0` (if 0 is not an actual value that will be used for that field), or change `CreatedBy` to be of type `int?`.

Comment: A variable set to be a 32-bit unsigned integer cannot be `null`.  You would have to make CreatedBy a `nullable` varible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `CreatedBy` is `int` which is a type that cannot take the value `null`.

From what you currently have, it is not possible to detect whether or not `CreatedBy` has been set. Suppose that its default value is `0`. Then the value is set to `1`, and then back to `0`. Now, how can you distinguish the current `0` from the original unmodified `0`?

If what you want to do is detect whether or not the value is `0`, well I don't think I need to tell you how to do that. If you really want to detect whether or not the value has ever been set you'll need to maintain a `bool` flag and set that flag the first time the property's setter executes.

Answer (score 7):

`int` is a value type which means it can never be null. Its default value is 0. If you want store null instead of 0, you need to change the type to `int?`, which is a nullable int type. To read more about Nullable types, check "[Nullable Types (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)"

Answer (score 3):

The int value is a type of non `Nullable` types see
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

if you want to check if set or not use

```
//GetValueOrDefault()


private int? createdBy;

public int CreatedBy 
{
  get { return createdBy.GetValueOrDefault(-1); }
  set { createdBy= value; }
}



///your code

if(e.CreatedBy == -1)
{
//not set
}else
{
//set
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, encapsulating `int?` behind an `int` property!

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a value type which can't be null. If you want to make a value type nullable, you need to use `int?` which is a shorthand way of creating a `Nullable` object like this

```
Nullable<int> myNullable = new Nullable<int>();
```

Comment: `Nullable` is not a reference type, it's a value type.

Comment: @Servy is right. Nullable is a struct which is a value type.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone help tell me how I can check if the value of CreatedBy has not been set yet?

No, that is impossible since value types (like int) can't be null.

But you can use [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which let's you declare it as a "Nullable of int" and then it can be null.

From the documentation I linked to:

> A nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value

To make your property a "Nullable of int", just add a questionmark:

```
public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

The above syntax is actually just a shorthand for:

```
public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because default value of int is 0 not null. `e.CreatedBy` never going to have the value like `null` so better is to compare it with 0.

```
if (e.CreatedBy == 0)
```

`nullable` int can be equal to null but not nullable (default int) never going to be equal of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are using **int** not **[nullable int](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-int)** so it can't be null ever?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the definition of your `CreatedBy` as follows:

`public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }`

and they you can make the following check

`if (e.CreatedBy == null)` or `if (e.CreatedBy.HasValue)`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lot's of answers explaining the obvious. Here's a couple of ideas for actually solving your problem:

**One alternative:** Just use the default value 0.

Now, instead of checking for `null` in your original code, you can check  `if(CreatedBy > 0)`.

If you prefer to be more "explicit", you could use -1 to explicitly indicate "empty" or "not set", by setting it as a default value in the constructor. I'm not saying this is ideal in all situations, but it is fairly simple:

```
public YourClass(){
     CreatedBy = -1;
}

public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

Obviously, this leads to the test: `if(CreatedBy != -1)`.

**Another alternative** is to use `nullable of int`, as some have sugested, and check for `null`. This has the downside of having to deal with the type `int?` instead of the more "general" `int` everywhere you work with that value though. That may not be a problem, but sometimes it can get annoying, especially if you pass the value to other methods, classes, or whatever..

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can't check whether the value has been set, you can only check what value it has now. Any property will have a 'default' value when it's initialised. For most types (including Nullable), the default value is null, however for int the default value is 0.

If you're sure that nobody would ever set this property to 0 for any other reason, then you can test for:

```
if (e.CreatedBy == 0)
```

...however, if 0 is a valid value for this property under another circumstance, then testing for 0 won't help you. Equally, it you change the property to nullable, then you can test for:

```
if (e.CreatedBy == null)
```

...as per your original design, but if there is any other reason why the property might be set to null then again you're not finding out if it had ever been set, only that the last time it was set, it was set to null.

If you want to really know whether the value has been set, you need to arrange for something else to happen when the setter is used, for example to set another flag. Here's an example of doing exactly this, where the CreatedByHasBeenSet property is false (the default value of bool!) until the setter on CreatedBy is called:

```
    private int createdBy;

    public int CreatedBy
    {
        get
        {
            return this.createdBy;
        }

        set
        {
            this.createdBy = value;
            this.CreatedByHasBeenSet = true;
        }
    }

    public bool CreatedByHasBeenSet { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Hello @Ramhound, the question being asked is "how can I tell if the value has been set?" My point is that even with int?, you can't tell if it's been set, only what it has been set to - null is just one possible value for the variable. If 0 isn't a valid value for this property to be set to, then testing for zero is fine.

Comment: I was only trying to get you to improve your answer.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, have edited the answer to incorporate your suggestions